# Trying to import "matplotlib" (which is already installed), it appears the following error:

Tags: python, matplotlib, pycharm

I'm receiving the following error when trying to import matplotlib in Pycharm:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/E490/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/main.py", line 1, in <module>
    import matplotlib
  File "C:\Users\E490\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 174, in <module>
    _check_versions()
  File "C:\Users\E490\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 159, in _check_versions
    from . import ft2font
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing ft2font: The specified module could not be found.
```

Answer (score 0):

Your environment is probably messed up, try creating a new one and test it!
Execute the following commands in your terminal:

```
python3 -m venv test_env
source test_env/bin/activate
pip3 install matplotlib
python3 -c "import matplotlib"
```

If you don't get any errors its fixed